# $f \circ g =\operatorname{ id}$ and $g \circ f \neq \operatorname{id}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, inverse

Are there two functions $f$ and $g$ s.t.
$$f \circ g = \operatorname{id}$$
but
$$g \circ f \neq \operatorname{id}?$$
Could someone give an example or a proof that this is impossible?

This must be trivial, but I can't figure it out. :) Thanks!

Comment: Try $g:n\mapsto n+1$ and $f:n\mapsto \max\{0,n-1\}$ on the set of nonnegative integers.

Answer (score 13):

**Hint:** Consider the two functions on the integers:
$$
f(x)=\left\lfloor\frac x2\right\rfloor
$$
and
$$
g(x)=2x
$$

Comment: Why all of the downvotes (on each answer)?

Comment: Seems like the simplest answer to me :) Thanks!

Comment: I was just wondering that as well - also, nice example.

Comment: @robjohn Should the downvotes on each answer be flagged or it is enough that the Moderator has already observed this?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: there is not much that can be done about this unless it seems there is targeted voting. I don't think the script that detects targeted voting will be triggered here. It is possible that someone thought that these answers were not good. One of the answers has now gotten 2 downvotes, so it seems there is more than 1 downvoter.

Comment: There is also a vote to close. Wonder if it is the same person.

Comment: See above the result.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{0\}$ and define the functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ so that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $g(0)=0$.
Then $f\circ g:B\to B$ is the identity but $g\circ f:A\to A$ maps everything to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$.

If $B$ is a singleton then $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_B$.

($\operatorname{id}_B$ is *unique* as function $B\rightarrow B$)

If $B$ is a singleton and $A$ is not a singleton then $g\circ f\neq \operatorname{id}_A$.

($g\circ f$ is *constant* and $\operatorname{id}_A$ is not)

---

Nice to remember:

> $s\circ i=\operatorname{id}$

Here $s$ stands for surjective and $i$ for injective. So from $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}$ you are allowed to conclude that $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective. A more general version (for later, if there is some familiarity with categories) is:

> $r\circ s=\operatorname{id}$

Here $r$ for retraction and $s$ for section.

These mnemonics are very valuable to me.

Answer (score 1):

To treat this matter properly, one must consider the functions as having well-defined
domains and co-domains (or sources and targets, if preferred).  For the above compositions
to even make sense, we must have
$$
f: A \to B 
$$
and
$$
g: B \to A .
$$
Now the compositions are
$$
f\circ g: B \to B    
$$
and
$$
g\circ f: A \to A,
$$
so if $A$ and $B$ are different, the two compositions have no chance of being the same.

BUT, even if $f\circ g = id_B$, we still need not get $g\circ f = id_A$.

Example:   $A = \{ -1 , 1 \}$     and  $B = \{ 1 \}$ 
with $g(1) = 1$   and  $f(-1) = f(1) = 1$.

(This is just the square/squareroot example that was mentioned earlier.)

Bill Taylor

Comment: Please use LaTeX for your answers. They look much prettier!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Consider $\sin$ and $\arcsin$ on their natural domains.

Answer (score 0):

Take the space of polynomials, $f = $ differentiation and $g = $ integration.

Then $f \circ g = \operatorname{id}$ but $g \circ f \ne \operatorname{id}$ because $g(f(x^2+1))=g(2x)=x^2$.

Comment: Hmm, you should be more precise what you mean be "integration". How do you pick one of the primitive functions? Or do you have definite integration in mind?

Comment: @Dirk, integration is just indefinite integration with no constants, that is, $\int x^n=\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$.

Comment: As far as I know "indefinite integral" stands for any antiderivative of a function and your operator has to choose one of them. Or is there any canonical choice that can be made?

Answer (score 0):

To work out a pair of function $f$ and $g$ that satisfies these conditions the following  lemmas are helpful.

**Lemma 1:**

If $$f \circ g = \operatorname{id} \tag{1}$$ then $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective.

$\blacksquare$

I ommit the proof of this well known lemma. From lemma 1 follows the next lemma.

**Lemma 2:**

If $$f \circ g = \operatorname{id}$$ and $g$ is surjective then $$g \circ f = \operatorname{id}$$

$\blacksquare$

**Proof:**

$g$ is injective by lemma 1 and surjective, so it is bijective and $f$ is its inverse.

$\blacksquare$

So let's assume that 
$$g:A \mapsto B$$
satisfies $(1)$.
So $g$ must be a injective but not surjective. We define
$$C:=g(B)$$
Then $$C \subsetneqq B$$ and $$g:A \mapsto C$$ is bijective.
We define $$f|_C: C \mapsto A$$ as  $$f|_C:=g^{-1}|_C$$ and define $$f|_{B\setminus C}: B\setminus C \mapsto A $$ arbitrary.
The $f$ and $g$ have the desired properties:

$$f \circ g = \operatorname{id} $$ because $$f|_C \circ g = \operatorname{id}$$
We have $$(g \circ f)|_C=\operatorname{id}|_C$$
But for $b \in B \setminus C$ we have $$(g \circ f) (b)=c \in C$$ and so $b \ne c$. But we have $$(g \circ f) (b) \ne c$$ and so $g \circ f$ is not injective.

**Example 1**

Choose an injective but not surjective function $g$, e.g. 
$$\exp: \to e^x$$
$$\exp: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$$
Then we have
$$A=\mathbb{R}$$
$$B=\mathbb{R}$$
$$C=\mathbb{R^+}$$
We have $$f|_\mathbb{R^+}=\log$$ and we define $$f: x \to x, \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R_0^\textbf{-}} $$

$\blacksquare$

**Example 2**

$M$ is an arbitrary set with $m \in M$ and $q \notin M$. We define 
$$A:=M$$
$$B:=M \cup \{q\}$$
and the functions $g$
$$g:M \mapsto M \cup \{q\}$$
$$g: x \to x$$

We have 
$$C=M$$
and 
$$f:M \cup \{q\} \mapsto M $$
$$f: x \to 
\begin{cases} x, \; \forall x \in M \\
m , \mbox{if } x=q
\end{cases}
$$

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to define the functions via matrices, in which case the product of the matrices is not commutative - I don't know if that is quite what you are looking for. You could also define the functions by $f(x) = x^2$, $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$, where $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0 , \infty)$ and $g: [0 , \infty) \to [0 , \infty)$. Here, $f(g(x)) = x $ but $g(f(x)) = |x|$. There are of course other examples of similar type.

Comment: You should take $f$ from $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @user10676 Ah, how very sloppy of me! I see what you mean - I neglected to allow $f \circ g$ to be defined - fixing this now.